# ERD entities for a movie actor database: how to distinguish actors?

Tags: erd

I am making an ERD for movies/actors database.

Question I need help with:
"right now we have two columns for actors (lead actors and supporting actors).
If both actors' categories are in the same Entity-how would you identify which is a lead and which is a supporting actor in each movie?”.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rather ambiguous narrative:

> right now we have two columns for actors (lead actors and supporting actors) (...) in the same entity (...)

You would have an ERD like:

[image]

The name of the column, i.e. `lead_actors`, `supporting_actors` should obviously answer your question about identifying the leads and the supporting actors.

However this design requires improvement, considering that there are usually 3-4 lead actors and a lot more supporting actors:

- If the two columns would mean all the actors of each category ("actors" in plural), the design would not comply with the principle of atomicity of the [first normal form](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm).  Let's take the example of a movie A [*beautiful mind*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268978/): `lead_actors` would be "*Russel Crowe, Jennifer Connelly, Ed Harris*", and `supporting_actors` would be a very long list. This would not allow to efficiently find all the movies in which "Jennifer Connelly" is lead or supporting actors.
- If you'd split the actors of a movie in a separate table the principle of atomicity could be met.  However, this would require to have the same number of lead actors and supporting actors, which is not realistic. Moreover this design allows inconsistencies (e.g. a same actor being lead actor in one row and supporting actor in the same movie, or twice lead actor which would be redundant):
  [image]
- To get it right, the usual approach is to have an `actor` entity, and an associative entity (e.g. `ActorMovie`) that would tell which actor plays in which movie.  Lead vs supporting could then be a simple attribute in the association table:
  [image]